# Can you use Task Scheduler from python?

Tags: python, windows-task-scheduler

I would like to use python to schedule a task in Windows Task Scheduler. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this might be to run `SCHTASKS.EXE` commands with the `os` module:

```
import os
os.system('SCHTASKS /CREATE /SC DAILY ...')
```